# A module's global variable

Tags: c, global-variables

I have a module of 2 files: the header (`module.h`) and the implementation (`module.c`). The function of this module are used in another `.c` file.

I want a module to have a global variable that won't get reinitialized every time a function of this module is called. Said variable will be modified only from within the module.

To give you a better picture:

`module.c`:

```
int glob_var;
int func(); //It modifies `glob_var`'s value
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "module.h"
func();
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: make it static then.

Answer (score 2):

> Said variable will me modified only from within the module

Since the variable is going to be modified/needed only in `func()`, you don't need it as a global variable. Declare it as `static` within `func()`.

```
int func(void)
{
   static int var = 0;
   /* Do stuff */

   /* Modify 'var' */
}
```

In general, you should avoid global variables whenever you can. In your case, you don't need it. Notice that `var` will not be reinitialized when `func()` is called multiple times as it's a `static` variable.

Comment: I tried to play around with this evening, but declaring var static doesn't seem to do the trick, neither when declared inside nor outside fun(). is it important to mention that func is actually a main function and that module.c is a program I execute by means of exec* functions? So what I want is the module's main function retain its data between two calls. Like: execl("mymodule", (char *) NULL) makes var's value 1, and another exec'"mymodule", (char *) NULL) makes it two. Thanks.

Comment: *"is it important to mention that func is actually a main function and that module.c is a program I execute by means of exec* functions"* No. *"So what I want is the module's main function retain its data between two calls. Like: execl("mymodule", (char *) NULL) makes var's value 1, and another exec'"mymodule", (char *) NULL) makes it two"*. This is the reason why it doesn't "work". `exec*` functions are not like a normal function call. They repace your process image with a new one. They don't *return* at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use static modifier to your glob_var.

Answer (score 0):

module.c:

```
static int glob_var;
int func(); //It modifies glob_var's value
```

main.c:

```
#include "module.h"
func()
```